# Passing class names to dictionary (and parsing order)

Tags: python, class, parsing

I have some code that looks like the following:

```
class Action(object):
    ...

class SpecificAction1(Action):
    ...

class SpecificAction2(Action):
    ...
```

They are all specified in the same file. Before their specification I want to put a dictionary that looks like this:

```
ACTIONS = {
    "SpecificAction1": SpecificAction1,
    "SpecificAction2": SpecificAction2
}
```

The idea is that I can simply import the ACTIONS dictionary from other modules and have this one dictionary be the one canonical string representation of the actions (they are sent over the network and other places where I need some identifier).

Is it possible to do "class pointers" like this in the same way you do function pointers? And my editor complains that names are undefined before the dictionary is declared before the class definitions - is this true?

Also, if the above is possible can I do this to instantiate a class: `ACTIONS['SpecificAction2']()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes are [first-class citizens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen) in Python, i.e. you can treat them like any other object. From that point of view your construction is perfectly fine, except that you have to define `ACTIONS` dictionary at the end of the file (because unlike some other languages the order is important in Python: it will throw a ReferenceError otherwise).

There's even more. You could use some metaprogramming to simplify this. Consider this (Python2.x, the syntax is a bit different in 3.x):

```
ACTIONS = {}

class MyMeta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, nmspc):
        super(MyMeta, cls).__init__(name, bases, nmspc)
        if name != "Action": # <--- skip base class
            ACTIONS[name] = cls

class Action(object):
    __metaclass__ = MyMeta
    ...

class SpecificAction1(Action):
    ...

class SpecificAction2(Action):
    ...
```

It will automatically populate `ACTIONS` dictionary with any class which inherits from `Action` class (because `Action` class has `MyMeta` as a `__metaclass__`). Read more about metaprogramming here:

https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Metaprogramming.html

As for `ACTIONS['SpecificAction2']()`: yes, it will create a new instance of the class, it's perfectly valid code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that. Python is a dynamic language and allows you to just that. However, from your `ACTIONS` dict, the values are definitions of classes. If you want to provide them over network, pass them as strings and use `getattr`

```
ACTIONS = {
    "SpecificAction1": 'SpecificAction1',
    "SpecificAction2": 'SpecificAction2'
}
```

And them import the files containing the definitions:

```
module = __import__('my_actions_module')
class_ = getattr(module,ACTIONS.get('SpecificAction1'))
instance = class_()
```

and `instance` is what you need.

Comment: My point was that the key will be the string name I put over the wire. This way I can keep the implementations in that dictionary (imagine the same code running on both ends) and switch it out with another class without affecting the name used to represent that action.

Comment: If you want to keep the implementation in the dictionary, you won't be able to find the key that easily. And if you want to send the dict over the network, you should use http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html.